# Doctrine DQL Can I not dot into related objects? eg. todo.todoList.project

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I think I am getting the error "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 194: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '.'"

Because my DQL is invalid (3rd line)?

```
SELECT COUNT(t.id) AS numTasks, COUNT(t.completedOn) AS numCompleted
FROM Application\Models\Todo t
WHERE t.todoList.project = :proj  
AND t.assigned = :user
```

How can I drill down into related elements? A Project have TodoLists, TodoLists have Todos. So I am trying to get the total number of todos & completed todos where the todo comes from the specified project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an explicit LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN. That would have been done under the hood anyways.

Comment: isit something like `... FROM Application\Models\Todo t JOIN t.todoList l ...`